# Events in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt4, qgraphicsview

I'm having trouble getting events in `QGraphicsView` working. I've subclassed `QGraphicsView` and tried to overload the `mousePressEvent` and `wheelEvent`. But neither `mousePressEvent` nor `wheelEvent` get called.

Here's my code (Edited a few things now):

Declaration:

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
class rasImg: public QGraphicsView
{
public:
rasImg(QString file);
~rasImg(void);
    initialize();
QGraphicsView *view;
QGraphicsScene *scene;
private:
virtual void mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent  *event);
virtual void wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent  * event );
}
```

Definition:

```
#include "rasImg.h"
void rasImg::initialize()
{
view = new QGraphicsView();
scene = new QGraphicsScene(QRect(0, 0, MaxRow, MaxCol));
scene->addText("HELLO");
scene->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,100,100));
view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
view->setScene(scene);
}
void rasImg::mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent  *event)
{
    qDebug()<<"Mouse released";
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,0,0));
}
void rasImg::wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent  * event )
{
qDebug()<<"Mouse released";
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,0,0));
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?.
Why don't I see a message or background color change when I click the view or use the mouse wheel?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but why you create new QGraphicsView inside QGraphicsView? Consider removing "view"-variable and instead of view->setXxx just setXxx.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the events because they're being handled by the `scene` object you're creating, not your class.

Remove the `QGraphicsScene *scene;` from your `rasImg` and try something like this for the constructor:

```
rasImg::rasImg(QString file)
  : QGraphicsScene(QRect(0, 0, MaxRow, MaxCol))
{
 addText("HELLO");
 setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,100,100));
 setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);

 view = new QGraphicsView();
 view->setScene(this);
}
```

If you want that in two steps, you could do:

```
rasImg::rasImg(QString file)
  : QGraphicsScene()
{
  // any constructor work you need to do
}


rasImg::initialize()
{
 addText("HELLO");
 setSceneRect(QRect(0, 0, MaxRow, MaxCol));
 setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,100,100));
 setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);

 view = new QGraphicsView();
 view->setScene(this);
}
```

The point is that the scene that is displayed must be an actual instance of your `rasImg`, not an instance of `QGraphicsScene`.

If it's the view you're subclassing, do the same thing. The view you're displaying must be an instance of your class, not a plain `QGraphicsView`.

```
rasImg::rasImg(QString file)
    : QGraphicsView()
{
   // constructor work
}

void rasImg::initialize()
{
  scene = new QGraphicsScene(QRect(0, 0, MaxRow, MaxCol));
  scene->addText("HELLO");
  scene->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(100,100,100));

  setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
  setScene(scene);
}
```

Comment: Well in my actual code I have QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView  initialized in another function. I put it in the constructor for simplicity. Take a look at the code now...how would I proceed?

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in the code...I've subclassed qgraphicsview not qgraphicsScene...I've edited my code a bit now...Could you take a look.

Comment: Thanks that was perfect...Got my code running...didn't realize I had two seperate QGraphicsViews initialized.

Answer (score 1):

QGraphicsView is derived from QWidget. Therefore it receives mouse events like regular widgets. If your code really is

```
void rasImg::mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
```

It can not receive events since it should be

```
void rasImg::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent *event )
```

[QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html) is for items in QGraphicsScene that receive mouse input.

Comment: Then you have something other going on, since I am currently looking at class derived from QGraphicsView that uses mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) and it does receive events.

Try sorting out the problem by doing something very simple first.

Comment: You should at least see debug output from event. Background can't change, since you are changing it from scene that is not attached to view that receives those events. That's a bit messy part you have there.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to handle clicks on a specific GUI element rather than handle click on the whole scene, you should derive your own class either from `QGraphicsItem` (see example of `SimpleClass` [here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qgraphicsitem.html)) or derive from one of existing elements, e.g. `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

In both cases in your derived class you can override `void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);`